How to specify build_file in http_archive?
I am using http_archive to load in a repo. The repo already has a BUILD file (https://github.com/mongodb-forks/bazel_clang_tidy/blob/v1.0/BUILD). I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for build_file in my http_archive() invocation.
Here's the current configuration:
http_archive(
    name = "bazel_clang_tidy",
    build_file = "//bazel_clang_tidy-1.0:BUILD",
    url = "https://github.com/mongodb-forks/bazel_clang_tidy/archive/refs/tags/v1.0.tar.gz",
)

I've tried variations on build_file, e.g.:
//BUILD
://BUILD
//:BUILD
(and so on)
But I keep getting the error: BUILD file not found in any of the following directories.
I'm hoping there's just some obscure syntax here that I'm not understanding. (I've searched around and seen that a lot of other folks have encountered variations of this problem).

BTW, I added strip_prefix = "bazel_clang_tidy-1.0" and removed the build_file line, and it apparently works now! So, is that the recommended solution?

In short yes, you build_file is meant to add BUILD file to the dependencies repository. If it already has one, you don't need to / should not add it.

Don't set build_file at all. It's an optional attribute, if you don't specify it then the file from the archive will be used.
Like this:
http_archive(
    name = "bazel_clang_tidy",
    url = "https://github.com/mongodb-forks/bazel_clang_tidy/archive/refs/tags/v1.0.tar.gz",
)

(Also, indirectly related, you shouldn't rely on the github source tarballs to have a stable checksum. They have changed it in the past and broken lots of builds, and may do so again in the future. See https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/45830 for example.)

Aha, thanks. I figured out that if I use strip_prefix, then Bazel successfully finds the build file. Thanks!
